# How to create a two column format for an iframe pdf in tumblr

Tags: html, iframe, tumblr

I would like to know how to format 2 pdf iframe to form in a 2 column not below on top of each other.
[3col-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c449g.jpg)
[mypage-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmbQB.jpg)

```
<p><iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ctZfL6Qn_HTETYWy_EwSDcziSWDWKrrZ/preview" width="640"></iframe></p>

<p><iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_d9a9XYmglngdxQ3JnQ3x9XMzQMhAJ2S/preview" width="640"></iframe></p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap is very good for this. But if you want to roll your own, just assign a percentage width to each wrapper. I would so this with classes but for the sake of argument `<p style="width:50%"><iframe1></p><p style="width:50%"><iframe2></p>` % width don't work with margins but they do work with padding. If you have a 3rd column which is part of the full width of the page, you can do 20%, 40%, 40% etc.

Comment: @lharby thanks for this! I tried it but I just managed to get the scaling of the iframe pdf. is there a way to have it side by side?

Comment: `<p><p style="width:100%"><iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ctZfL6Qn_HTETYWy_EwSDcziSWDWKrrZ/preview" width="640"></iframe></p>
<p><p style="width:100%"><iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_d9a9XYmglngdxQ3JnQ3x9XMzQMhAJ2S/preview" width="640"></iframe></p>`

Comment: Should be. I will try and make a jsfiddle later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

Firstly there is a hardcoded value of width being passed to the iframes, I don't know that you can edit this but you can overide with css.

Instead of relying on inline styles I would abstract the code so that it uses class names and is reusable elsewhere and then it will be easier to edit the css properties than the html (IMHO).

Here is your html

```
<p>
<p style="width:50%">
   <iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ctZfL6Qn_HTETYWy_EwSDcziSWDWKrrZ/preview" width="640"></iframe>
</p>
<p>
<p style="width:50%">
  <iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_d9a9XYmglngdxQ3JnQ3x9XMzQMhAJ2S/preview" width="640"></iframe>
</p>
```

I have changed both paragraph wrappers to only be 50% width. But also added `float: left` in the css.

Some additional css:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

p iframe {
    width: 100% !important; // this will override the hard coded width property
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/k5goj7wd/)

I would not use a p element as if you do write css and only target paragraphs it could disrupt code elsewhere, either make a class for 50% width like `.half` etc or create a div wrapper with a parent class and then you can target the paragraphs inside that. `<div class="wrapper"><p>Paragraph text</p></div>` etc. Then you can write

```
.wrapper p {
   width: 50%
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your comments below here is the inline css which should work OK:

```
<p style="width:50%; float:left;">
   <iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ctZfL6Qn_HTETYWy_EwSDcziSWDWKrrZ/preview" width="100%"></iframe>
</p>
<p>
<p style="width:50%; float:left;">
  <iframe height="480" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_d9a9XYmglngdxQ3JnQ3x9XMzQMhAJ2S/preview" width="100%"></iframe>
</p>
```

Note that each p element has `width: 50%` and `float: left` properties, and the iframe width have been changed to 100%.

Updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/k5goj7wd/1/)

Comment: Thanks again for this one. My problem now is putting the css code into html. I'm using google drive in uploading my files. is it possible to call in css using this one? or is there a free site to let me call in uploaded css?

Comment: the tumblr page im working on has only the HTML function.

Comment: You have a couple of options, you can edit the whole Tumblr template and add css into the style tag, this will work across other pages if you use similar selectors. Alternatively each post/page is editable via HTML, see attached. You can toggle between plain text/HTML and enter custom css if you want. Inline styles are OK. I always try and think about making code reusable. https://imgur.com/SnyVqOf

Comment: I see, I think im going to go with the inline style.

Comment: `p {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

p iframe {
    width: 100% !important; // this will override the hard coded width property
}` this code works but it messes up the 1st page. how do I add this into an HTML inline style?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JOIKOcm_nE49nYwI5B6A76YZ0_r6dvu0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe you should only write inline styles in this instance then. Forget writing any css.

Comment: Sorry I ask alot of question. I'm a novice but I would like to know on how to make the css that you gave me into an inline style. the code that you gave me works fine on the page as it aligns them side by side.

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer and linked to a new jsfiddle which shows the code working. If this helps you please vote on my answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much! It works perfectly. thanks again for all the help!